# Python Printing Prime Numbers

Tags: python

TASK : Write a program that prints out all the primes below 10,000.
Hint: you will need to use % which gives the remainder of a division operation.
So x=11%5 would give 1 as 11/5=2 remainder 1

I FOUND THIS CODE , can someone add annotations next to all the lines explaining what is happening.I totally don't understand this code.

```
    numbers=[]
for i in range(0,10001):
    numbers.append(" ") #We just put spaces in each box for now
numbers[0]="X"
numbers[1]="X"

firstFree=2
while firstFree<10001:
multiple=firstFree*2
  while multiple<10001: #Mark all multiples of firstFree as X
      numbers[multiple]='X'
      multiple=multiple+firstFree

     firstFree=firstFree+1
      while firstFree<10000 and numbers[firstFree]=='X':
    firstFree=firstFree+1

  for i in range(0,10001):
         if(numbers[i]!='X'):
              print(i)
```

Comment: It doesn't come off like you've tried much yourself and that will hardly get you any help. This isn't a tutorial/teaching site, but a Q&A.

Comment: Getting a code and then try to understand it... that's not the right way to go. The right way is to build the logic first, then try to implement the logic with a programming language.

Comment: @AhsanulHaque I am currently learning Lists in Python ,this is the last task I have to do , and its the only one I have no idea how to do.

Comment: With all due respect, it's not a question worth answering as currently written. Read on [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also consider how your question can also be useful to future readers. Unless they're dealing with this exact code, it's probably pointless. And that's why this isn't just a service to write someone's code, debug, or such. If you need every line explained, it's probably a sign of having to take a step back and learn the language before you try to write/understand some code. FAQ for [asking questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).

Answer (score 0):

As you have been told, you should not learn that way. Plus, in my humble opinion, this code you have found is extremely ugly and hard to read.

This is beter example.

```
#Main loop, this is self explanatory.
for dividend in range(2, 10000):

    #This loops through all divisors available.
    for divisor in range(2, dividend):

        #Check against reminder of division.
        if dividend % divisor == 0:

            #Prints all composites of prime number that failed against check.
            print('{} equals {} * {}'.format(dividend, divisor, dividend//divisor))

            #Breakes second loop.
            break

    #Find answer for this thing yourself. It is interesting.
    else:
        #Enters here when have not found division factor.
        print('{} is one of the prime numbers.'.format(dividend))
```

Read tons of tutorials, train and learn.